# Dropbox API working, now trying to copy images to Amazon S3 with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, dropbox, carrierwave

I have an ipad app that uses dropbox to sync images to the cloud so that i can access them with a webapp and process them etc etc.

the part i'm having trouble with is getting the file from dropbox to s3 via carrierwave. i have a photo model and i can create a new photo and upload and an image successfully. I can also put a file on dropbox. However when i try to get a file off of dropbox and put it on s3, the contents of the file is just text.

Are there some sort of mime types i need to set or something?

I am using `dropbox_sdk` and the `get_file_and_metadata` method. It returns me the file object successfully, but the contents are all just text. this is me hard coding the image file so i can be sure it exists..

```
dbsession = DropboxSession.deserialize(session[:dropbox_session])
@client = DropboxClient.new(dbsession, ACCESS_TYPE) #raise an exception if session not authorized
@info = @client.account_info # look up account information
@photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
@db_image metadata = @client.get_file_and_metadata('/IMG_1575.jpg')
```

the part i don't know how to do is say take this image `@db_image` and use that file when creating a new `photo` and store it on S3.

I'm thinking it might be a 'mime type' issue, but i've read that that is only based on the file ext.

any insight you guys could share would really help me get past this hurdle. thanks!

Comment: this doesn't really answer your question, but get_file_and_metadata returns two things.  If you just want the image file, and not that metadata, i think you want to do "@db_image, metadata = @client.get_file_and_metadata('/IMG_1575.jpg')"

Comment: I tried that as well. It's just a different way to get the same problem. I can get the data, but it's all just text. thanks for the reply though. i edited the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. Instead I used the `direct_url.url` method that is part of the `dropbox-api` gem used with the `carrierwave` gem. the `direct_url.url` method returns a secure full url path to that file that you can use as the `remote_url` value for carrierwave.

```
@client = Dropbox::API::Client.new(:token  => 'derp', :secret => 'derp')
@dropbox_files = @client.ls "images/#{@event.keyword}/#{photo_size}/"

@dropbox_files.each do |f|
  photo_exists = Photo.where(:dropbox_path => f.direct_url.url).count
  if photo_exists == 0
    @photo = Photo.create(:remote_filename_url => f.direct_url.url, 
                          :dropbox_path => f.direct_url.url,
                          :event_id => @event.id)
  end
end
```

Now, i'm pretty new at ruby, so i'll be posting a better way to step through the results, as that seems pretty slow and clunky.